# Can someone tell me what this IC is?

Tags: pcb, identification, replacement

I was Hoping someone smarter than me could help. I am looking for a replacement IC that blew up on a board.  I was able to get a picture of the chip from another board to get the markings. The chip reads:

ATD5984
DA01D1C

From what I can see the top markings appear to be a motor driver of some kind, maybe a stepper motor etc however, I can't tell what the markings on the bottom are. I can't find this exact chip.  The closest I found had the same ATD5984 but the bottom read C9M01b1. I assume the bottom markings are features or capabilities of the ATD5984 chip

I am looking for a replacement of the ATD5984
DA01D1C chip. Is there something similar I could use? I put some pictures of the board and zoomed in pic of the IC for reference.

Thank You!
Dave
[image]

Comment: please edit the title to include the markings on IC

Answer (score 2):

Simple web search for ATD5984 shows [nearly full information](https://wmsc.lcsc.com/wmsc/upload/file/pdf/v2/lcsc/2012311902_ZHONGKEWEI-ATD5984_C1323230.pdf) about this stepping motor driver. The IC is widely available on Asian markets.

> I assume the bottom markings are features or capabilities of the
> ATD5984 chip

No, it is just a manufacturing code of date of manufacturing or batch number.

Comment: Thank you. That is what I was looking for. Cheers!

Comment: @Fishbone Although the specifications of the Zhongkewei part are mostly different (generally a bit lower voltage and temperature range, but with much better on-resistance) you might want to refer to the datasheet of the functionally very similar Allegro [A5984](https://www.allegromicro.com/en/products/motor-drivers/brush-dc-motor-drivers/a5984) if your Chinese is not up to par.